# assign/replace params hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the code sequence below in a rails controller action. Before the IF, params contains the request parameters, as expected. After it, params is nil. Can anyone please explain what is happening here?

```
if false
    params = {:user => {:name => "user", :comment => 'comment'}}
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar issue with code that tried to conditionally assign to params like this: `params ||= {}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `params` which contains the request parameters is actually a method call which returns a hash containing the parameters. Your `params =` line is assigning to a local variable called `params`.

After the `if false` block, Ruby has seen the local `params` variable so when you refer to `params` later in the method the local variable has precedence over calling the method of the same name. However because your `params =` assignment is within an `if false` block the local variable is never assigned a value so the local variable is `nil`.

If you attempt to refer to a local variable before assigning to it you will get a NameError:

```
irb(main):001:0> baz
NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
```

However if there is an assignment to the variable which isn't in the code execution path then Ruby has created the local variable but its value is `nil`.

```
irb(main):007:0> baz = "Example" if false
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> baz
=> nil
```

See: [Assignment - Local Variables and Methods in the Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods).

Comment: "Ruby has seen the local params" really, Ruby??? REALLY!!!??? O_o (sorry, but that cost me several days... Seeing is not executing, is it?)