# Params becomming nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

Had some old code that on some condition would modify params. I believe it was working before (not 100%). We are now getting params set to nil whether or not the condition is met.

The culprit is within the condition, I perform a `params = tmp.dup`. Even when the condition is false, this is causing an error in the update action.

I was able to recreate with a minimal test

(Rails 2.3.5)

```
rails bug;
cd bug;

script/generate scaffold bug name:string;
rake db:create;
rake db:migrate;
```

edit apps/controllers/bugs_controller.rb
add to beginning of update action

```
l_p = params.dup

if (false)

  params = l_p.dup  # NOT REACHED

end
```

script/server WEBrick -p 5001

browse to http://localhost:5001/bugs
create a new bug
edit bug
submit

Comment: your question seems to be pretty confusing to me. Could you please elaborate the scenario with some generic code so that we could understand it more precisely.

Comment: Yes, pretty confusing… Please elaborate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335825/assign-replace-params-hash-in-rails

Answer (score 6):

Per user45147 comment, the correct answer for this question is here:

[assign/replace params hash in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335825/assign-replace-params-hash-in-rails)

Copying here:

> The `params` which contains the request parameters is actually a
>   method call which returns a hash containing the parameters. Your
>   `params =` line is assigning to a local variable called `params`.
>
> After the `if false` block, Ruby has seen the local `params` variable
>   so when you refer to `params` later in the method the local variable
>   has precedence over calling the method of the same name. However
>   because your `params =` assignment is within an `if false` block the
>   local variable is never assigned a value so the local variable is
>   `nil`.
>
> If you attempt to refer to a local variable before assigning to it you
>   will get a NameError:
>
> ```
> irb(main):001:0> baz
> NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object
>         from (irb):1
> ```
>
> However if there is an assignment to the variable which isn't in the
>   code execution path then Ruby has created the local variable but its
>   value is `nil`.
>
> ```
> irb(main):007:0> baz = "Example" if false
> => nil
> irb(main):008:0> baz
> => nil
> ```