# Ruby interpreter magically assigns unreferenced variables?

Tags: ruby, interpreter, symbol-table

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> foo
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
  from (irb):1
  from /Users/justinwiley/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

So far so good, 'foo' is undefined.

```
irb(main):002:0> if false
irb(main):003:1> foo = 1
irb(main):004:1> end
=> nil
```

foo should still be undefined, but...

```
irb(main):005:0> foo
=> nil
```

Now it exists in the symbol table?  Since the logic in the if branch should never be reached, I would assume foo should remain undefined, instead of suddenly being nil?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1335890/163640

Comment: @eugen: I was looking for a good reference answer. Thanks for finding it. :)

Comment: Thanks eugen.  I'm trying to understand why Ruby has this behaviour?  Is this intentional or a side effect?

Comment: @juwiley: that's just how ruby works. local vars are created at parse time. Weird, but we have to live with it.

Comment: I dont think "thats just the way it is" is a good answer in computer science.  Heres a link to an answer with more details on why this behavior exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706664/interpretation-as-a-local-variable-overrides-method-name

Comment: @juwiley: you passed the test. :)